# Does entity_save() trigger the update event?

Tags: 7, entities

Not quite sure if calling entity_save() from code will trigger the update event or not.

So, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're asking whether or not `entity_save()` invokes `hook_entity_update()`: no, it doesn't.

The controller class (or save callback function) for an entity type may well invoke it (for example `node_save()` does), but you can't rely on it for an entity type without checking the code first.

Comment: Thanks. This means I will have to use `module_invoke_all('entity_update', $entity, 'entity_type')` on my own